How does schedule 7 of the Terrorism Act 2000 interact with the GDPR?
Schedule 7 of the Terrorism Act 2000 says you must give an examining officer any information they request:

5 A person who is questioned under paragraph 2 or 3 must—
(a) give the examining officer any information in his possession which the officer requests;

The GDPR requires you to establish a lawful basis for the data sharing with law enforcement authorities:

If you want to share personal data with a law enforcement authority you need a lawful basis under Article 6.
You must be satisfied that sharing personal data with a law enforcement authority is lawful. This means you must have a lawful basis under Article 6 of the UK GDPR before you share the personal data.
The “purpose limitation” principle in Article 5 of the UK GDPR states that “personal data shall be collected for specified, explicit and legitimate purposes and not further processed in a manner that is incompatible with those purposes”. This means you need to consider whether this new purpose is compatible with your original purpose.
The “crime and taxation: general exemption” may be available if you are sharing personal data with a law enforcement authority. This can exempt you from the purpose limitation requirement, meaning that you do not need to consider whether sharing personal data with a law enforcement authority is compatible with your original purpose for processing the personal data. However, you still have to comply with the requirement for the processing to be lawful, which means you still need a lawful basis.

Suppose one was being questioned under schedule 7 of the Terrorism Act 2000, you were asked questions relating to a third party whose data was covered by the GDPR, and your requests for the reason for the questions were rejected such that one could not establish a lawful basis for sharing the data, what would be the legal situation?  It would seem that not sharing the data would be illegal under the Terrorism Act, and sharing the data would be illegal under the GDPR.

Answers should also consider a scenario where a police officer is being dishonest (or it is a person impersonating a police officer), I.E. they've made up the claim something falls under Schedule 7 of the Terrorism Act 2000 but they haven't presented any evidence/required paperwork etc of said claim.

Now that the UK is outside the EU, it probably doesn’t.

@SCP-738 The UK still has GDPR.

My understanding is that UK adopted legislation equivalent in effect to GDPR at the time of withdrawal, but any changes made to the GDPR afterwards will not affect the UK.

@SCP-738 The UK has the UK GDPR, which is what I understand the OP to be referring to instead of the EU GDPR - it seems the most reasonable inference.

The GDPR lists compliance with legal obligations as a lawful basis under Article 6.
Article 6 of the GDPR lists the following as a lawful basis:

(c) processing is necessary for compliance with a legal obligation to which the controller is subject;

Presumably, a request from law enforcement under the Terrorism Act would count as a legal obligation to which you are subject as the data controller.

You don’t need to establish that your interrogator has a lawful basis; just that you do
Assuming you are satisfied that you are being interrogated under s5 (which is not something there’s likely to be any doubt about, you have a lawful basis (and a legal obligation) to disclose the information.
It’s not up to you to determine if HMG is complying with the GDPR.

From the linked document it seems it is up to you to establish some things: "We identify a lawful basis under Article 6", "We also identify a condition for processing under Article 9" and "We identify a condition for processing under Article 10", "We only share the minimum necessary amount of relevant and adequate personal data", "We ensure that the personal data is shared in compliance with our other data protection duties and obligations".
